# Split Array problem. Need help in understanding another approach

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I was solving this problem:

Given an integer array nums and an integer k, split nums into k non-empty subarrays such that the largest sum of any subarray is minimized.

Return the minimized largest sum of the split.

A subarray is a contiguous part of the array.

Example 1:

Input: nums = [7,2,5,10,8], k = 2
Output: 18
Explanation: There are four ways to split nums into two subarrays.
The best way is to split it into [7,2,5] and [10,8], where the largest sum among the two subarrays is only 18.
Example 2:

Input: nums = [1,2,3,4,5], k = 2
Output: 9
Explanation: There are four ways to split nums into two subarrays.
The best way is to split it into [1,2,3] and [4,5], where the largest sum among the two subarrays is only 9.

I could do this the following way. The idea is to have the relation like this:
`f(n) = Math.min(min, Math.max(sum_till_ith_element, f(n-1)))` i.e try possible combinations starting from i as 0 and keep reducing the sample size by 1 in the subsequent calls.

```
function splitArray(nums, m) {
    return recursive(nums, m, 0);
}
function recursive(nums, m, index, memo={}) {
    if(memo[''+m + index]) return memo[''+m + index];
    if(m === 1){
        let sum = 0;
        for(let i=index; i<nums.length; i++)
            sum += nums[i];
        return sum;
    }
    let min = Infinity;
    let sum = 0;
    for(let i=index; i<=nums.length-m; i++) {
        sum += nums[i];
        min = Math.min(min, Math.max(sum, recursive(nums, m-1, i+1, memo)));
        console.log(min)
    }
    memo[''+m + index] = min;
    return min;
}
```

Now I just bumped into another solution and what baffles me is the fact that it works perfectly fine even though I see that the recursive call still happens from ith onwards and hence without reducing the size `splitArray(boards.slice(i), k - 1)` and it still works. It reduces `k` though. In fact if you make slight changes like this, it would still work:
`for (let i = 1; i <= boards.length; i++) {`
I'd like to understand the reasoning behind this approach and the recurrence relation it establishes.

```
   function splitArray(boards, k, memo={}) {
    // Base Case
    if(memo[''+boards.join('')+k]) return memo[''+boards.join('')+k];
    if (k === 1) {
        return boards.reduce((sum, time) => sum + time, 0);
    }

    let minTime = Infinity;

    // Recursive Case
    for (let i = 0; i < boards.length; i++) {
        const timePartition = Math.max(
            boards.slice(0, i).reduce((sum, time) => sum + time, 0),
            splitArray(boards.slice(i), k - 1, memo)
        );
        minTime = Math.min(minTime, timePartition);
        console.log(minTime)
    }
    memo[''+boards.join('')+k] = minTime;
    return minTime;
    }
```

Comment: "It reduces `k` though."  You've answered your own question.  Your base case has to do with a low-enough value of `k` (although I would replace `=` with `<=` for degenerate cases), and your recursive case moves you toward that base case.  So it should always return.

Comment: Yeah but how does in theory does it make sense? For e.g in first iteration the result is going to be max(10, sumOfAllItems) how does that theoretically right?

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to think of this with simpler code.  Here we split out two helpers, one to calculate the sum of all numbers in an array (`sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) //=> 15`), and another to collect a range of numbers (`rng(3, 12) //=> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 19, 11]`.)

Then we can write a fairly simple recursive version like this:

```js
const rng = (lo, hi) => Array.from({length: hi - lo}, (_, i) => i + lo)
const sum = (ns) => ns.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)

const splitArray = (ns, k) =>
  ns.length == 0
    ? 0
  : k <= 1
    ? sum(ns)
  : Math.min(...rng(1, ns.length).map(i => Math.max(
      sum(ns.slice(0, i)), 
      splitArray(ns.slice(i), k - 1)
    )))

console.log(splitArray([7, 2, 5, 10, 8], 2))       //=> 18
console.log(splitArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2))        //=> 9
console.log(splitArray([8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9], 3))  //=> 14
```

The base cases should be obvious.  The recursive case, uses `rng` to find all the split-points between the first subarray and the rest of them, and, for each one, calculates the maximum of the sum of the first subarray and the result of a recursive call passing the remaining numbers and one less than our array counter.  Then it returns the minimum of these values.

This expresses the same algorithm as in your second example (except that it doesn't memoize.  We will add that below.)

Note that we are making progress at all times towards one of our base cases, when the array we're testing is empty, and when the array count is `1` (or below).

### Memoize

But without the memoization, we are clearly doing too much work.  But code written in this style is simple to memoize.  We add the cache parameter `memo`, defaulted to an empty object and sometimes, if the memoization key is not a simple parameter (like this instance), we default a memoization key parameter.  We add the `memo` to our recursive calls, and before we start, we check if the key is in the cache.  If it is, we return that value, and if not, we calculate the result, store it in the cache under our key and return it.  It could look like this, which should look quite similar to the original:

```js
const rng = (lo, hi) => Array.from({length: hi - lo}, (_, i) => i + lo)
const sum = (ns) => ns.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)

const splitArray = (ns, m, memo = {}, k = '' + ns + ':' + m) =>
  k in memo ? memo [k] : memo [k] = ns.length == 0
    ? 0
  : m <= 1
    ? sum(ns)
  : Math.min(...rng(1, ns.length).map(i => Math.max(
      sum(ns.slice(0, i)), 
      splitArray(ns.slice(i), m - 1, memo)
    )))

console.log(splitArray([7, 2, 5, 10, 8], 2))       //=> 18
console.log(splitArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2))        //=> 9
console.log(splitArray([8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9], 3))  //=> 14
```